# Share With form endless loop - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

There is a problem with sharing in site.

It is hard to explain, but it goes down something like that.

If I choose "Shared With", it will open new Window, where I should be able to select people, to share it with. But instead I get loading icon, that won't get me anywhere.

[image]

I get same result under different sub-sites. Does anyone have any idea, what might be the cause?

SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Comment: Do you have customized Master Page/CSS?

Comment: It seems, that there are. There is a yellow padlock in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution here: [List Item "Shared With" dialog error](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c9703b7b-a719-48b4-9350-9d9a75ac62e1/list-item-shared-with-dialog-error?forum=sharepointgeneral)

The problem was with `sharing.js` file. I had to replace `k.load(g,"ID","FileRef","FileLeafRef","Client_Title")` with `k.load(g,"ID","FileRef","FileLeafRef","Client_Title","Title")`. From there I got that view working again.